# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cars_count' referenced before assignment (counting objects within a function and a loop)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to out the number of cars within a video that shows cars, trucks and buses, I want to put a counter at the top right to count the number of cars and ignore the rest. I managed everything accept for the counting, the number keeps going back to zero but I have put cars_count = 0 outside def annotate_image and before annotated_img = annotate_image(frame) but I got the error

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cars_count' referenced before assignment.`

My Code is below.

```
def annotate_image(image):
  image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  results = model(image_rgb)
  cars_count = 0

  for i in range(len(results.pandas().xyxy[0].name)): 
    name = results.pandas().xyxy[0].name[i]
    startX = int(results.pandas().xyxy[0].xmin[i])
    startY = int(results.pandas().xyxy[0].ymin[i])
    endX = int(results.pandas().xyxy[0].xmax[i])
    endY = int(results.pandas().xyxy[0].ymax[i])
    confidence = results.pandas().xyxy[0].confidence[i]
    label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(name, confidence * 100)
      
    if confidence > 0.6:
      cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (255,0,0), 2)
      y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
      cv2.putText(image, label, (startX, y),
      cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 2)
      if name == "car":
        cars_count = cars_count + 1
      
  cars_count_label = "{}:".format(cars_count) 
  cv2.putText(image, cars_count_label, (600, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 2)

  return image

video_in_file = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/data/toycars.mp4"
video_out_file = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/data/out.mp4"

print("[INFO] accessing video stream...")
v_out = None

v_in = cv2.VideoCapture(video_in_file)
total_frame = int(v_in.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT ))

for frame_no in tqdm(range(total_frame), desc="Processing Video..."):
  (grabbed, frame) = v_in.read()

  # if the frame was not grabbed then we've reached the end of
  # the video stream so exit the script
  if not grabbed:
      print("[INFO] no frame read from stream - exiting")
      break
  
  annotated_img = annotate_image(frame)

  # check if the video writer is None
  if v_out is None:
      # initialize our video writer
      fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
      v_out = cv2.VideoWriter(video_out_file, fourcc, int(v_in.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)), (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), True)

  # write the output frame to disk
  v_out.write(annotated_img)

# release the file pointers
print("\n[INFO] cleaning up...")
v_out.release()
v_in.release()
```

Comment: share your video so your problem is reproducible

Comment: @TinoD I cannot share the video because it's personal but it's a video of a singular road and each few seconds a car, bus or truck drives by the camera, I think any online video that is similar to that description will help

Comment: the code you present cannot have raised the `UnboundLocalError` you say it did.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz it is not this code only when I put it outside the annotate image will it produce the function, for this code it's the numbers that keep going back to 0 whenever a car stops being recognized by the prediction

Comment: same user, same task: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77830577/how-to-permanently-label-an-object-once-the-confidence-hits-a-certain-percent